# Book for electromagnetic waves and radiation

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, resource-recommendations, vibrations

MIT course [8.03SC](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-03sc-physics-iii-vibrations-and-waves-fall-2016/syllabus/) recommends [Electromagnetic Vibrations Waves and Radiation (The MIT Press)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/electromagnetic-vibrations-waves-and-radiation) by Bekefi and Barrett  for extra reading however I am unable to find any soft copy online and its too costly to be purchased.

So kindly suggest some other textbooks which will cover the same content as this book or of the course 18.03 for electromagnetic module and which are available online.